# Solutions of $\sum_{i=1}^n e^{x_i} = n$ given certain conditions

Tags: calculus

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$. How would you prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n=3} e^{x_i} = 3$$ iff $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$?

- *Does the generalized proposition hold for an arbitrary $n$?*

Answer (score 7):

if $x+y+z=0$, then use jenson inequality (also AM-GM inequality)

$$e^x+e^y+e^z\ge 3e^{\frac{x+y+z}{3}}=3,x,y,z>0$$
iff $x=y=z$ ,so $x=y=z=0$

Comment: I could be wrong but it doesn't flow nicely that $x = y = z$ is implied from inequality set to 3? It's only equal to 3 iff all variables are $0$. I don't know If I am making self crystal clear here..but I get the approach :) +1

Comment: $a+b+c\ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc},a,b,c>0$ we known $=$ iff $a=b=c$, by this problem we have $e^x=e^y=e^z\Longrightarrow x=y=z$

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see the implicit AM-GM. Wish I could give another +1 ;).